# which is best popular open source logging software/program in c++ program area?

Tags: c++, logging

which is best popular open source log software/program in c++ program area?

I know log4cpp is one of logging programs, but it had memory leaking issue, So I want know which is popular and best one in production area?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from version 1.54.0, `Boost` has included [`boost.log`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/log/doc/html/index.html).